# Entire slider jumps on load - AnythingSlider

Tags: slider, anythingslider

I am using AnythingSlider to place content on this dev for a new site:

http://sitedev.lcadfiles.com/interactive_barrett.html

When the slider first loads on a given page, there is a slight jump (the entire slider, arrows, etc. moves a few pixels before settling into the correct position). After landing, it all appears to work fine. The shift doesn't appear to be browser specific, as it occurs on my older and newer machines with 4 different browsers (and various browser versions).

Is there something I have set wrong? I assume it might be somewhere global, like the anythingSlider.js (or perhaps the .css - though this seems less likely), but didn't see anything that stood out.

Comment: Make sure there isn't any padding or margins set on the `ul` and `li`'s - basically make sure to reset your css.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. A quick workaround (works for me).

eg. you have html code like below, add a style="visibility:hidden;" to your anythingslider container.

```
<div id="slider_nest" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <ul id="your_anythingslider">
    ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

in the js code, change the style to visible when document ready. eg.(JQuery)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#slider_nest').css('visibility', 'visible');
    ...
    $('#your_anythingslider').anythingslider();
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps!

**Update:** add a slider mask with a loader gif.

eg. in the html, you will have something like below:

```
<div id="slider_mask" style="background: #000 url('ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat center;     display:block; height:568px; width:1050px; margin:0 auto;">
</div>
<div id="slider_nest" style="display:none; height:568px; width:1050px; margin:0 auto;">
    <ul id="your_anythingslider">
    ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now in the js (JQuery):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#slider_mask').hide();
    $('#slider_nest').css({'display':'block'});
    ...
```

Comment: you can also use display property to replace visibility. in case of loading mass slides, you can also add a slider mask with a loader.gif, see the update

Answer (score 0):

OMG, this finally solved our problem! Thank you.

Since I'm using the Wordpress plugin on a custom theme, I had to adjust it a bit like this:

Add this before the shortcode in the **header.php** file:

```
<div id="slider_mask" style="background: #FFF url('ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat center;display:block; height:323px; width:940px; margin:0 auto;">
</div>
```

Add this in the  section of **header.php** file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider_mask').hide();           
    $('.anythingSlider').css({'display':'block'});
}
```

Add this to the **CSS** file:

```
.anythingSlider {display:none;}
```